# Having problem when running Selenium Maven project via Jenkins

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins

Same project works fine locally.

Error details:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -Dorg.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator.websocketConnectionTimeout=60
Running TestSuite
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Sep 22, 2021 1:46:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
/home/jenkins/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/x.x.x.x/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Sep 22, 2021 1:47:05 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 31.459 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
Test1(test.newTest)  Time elapsed: 30.295 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'XXX', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'x.x.x.x', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.10'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at test.newTest.Test1(newTest.java:48)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:27178/status] to be available after 20007 ms
    at test.newTest.Test1(newTest.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at test.newTest.Test1(newTest.java:48)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  newTest.Test1:48 » WebDriver Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Bui...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

**Question:**

Using chromedriver as Maven dependency in `pom.xml` file. Do I need to install Chrome browser on machine where Jenkins (on Linux) is installed ? I would really appreciate help on this.

Comment: Entire logs list is not applicable to your problem, I'd suggest to pay attention on last line - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Looks like it cannot instantiate driver there

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you confirm one thing, do I need to install chrome browser on machine where Jenkins(on Linux)is running ? I am using Maven dependency for chromedriver in the POM.XML file(instead of chromedriver file).

Comment: Keep an eye on this line: `error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so`. It does indeed indicate Chrome or its dependencies are not installed

Comment: In my situation, I am not allowed to install chrome browser on Jenkins machine. How can I handle it in the code/project ?